# How to apply kubernetes network policies to restrict access of namespace from other namespace?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes. I have this scenario for multi-tenancy

1) I have 3 namespaces as shown here:

```
 default,
 tenant1-namespace,
 tenant2-namespace
```

2) namespace `default` has two database pods

```
tenant1-db - listening on port 5432
tenant2-db - listening on port 5432
```

namespace `tenant1-ns` has one app pod

```
tenant1-app - listening on port 8085
```

namespace `tenant2-ns` has one app pod

```
tenant2-app - listening on port 8085
```

3) I have applied 3 network policies on default namespace

a) to restrict access to both db pods from other namespaces

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

b) to allow access to tenant1-db pod from tenant1-app of tenant1-ns only

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces-except-specific-pod-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant1-db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: tenant1-development
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tenant1-app
```

c) to allow access to tenant2-db pod from tenant2-app of tenant2-ns only

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces-except-specific-pod-2
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant2-db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: tenant2-development
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tenant2-app
```

I want to restrict access of tenant1-db to tenant1-app only, tenant2-db to tenant2-app only. But it seems tenant2-app can access tenant1-db which should not happen.

Below is db-config.js for tenant2-app

```
module.exports = {
  HOST: "tenant1-db",
  USER: "postgres",
  PASSWORD: "postgres",
  DB: "tenant1db",
  dialect: "postgres",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
};
```

As you can see I am pointing tenant2-app to use tenant1-db, I want to restrict tennat1-db to tenant1-app only? what modifications needs to do in network policies ?

**Updates :**

tenant1 deployment & Services yamls

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: tenant1-app-deployment
  namespace: tenant1-namespace 
spec: 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: tenant1-app 
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 1 pods matching the template 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: tenant1-app 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: tenant1-app-container 
        image: tenant1-app-dock-img:v1 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 8085 
--- 
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service  
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: tenant1-app-service
  namespace: tenant1-namespace  
spec: 
  selector: 
    app: tenant1-app 
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP 
    port: 8085 
    targetPort: 8085 
    nodePort: 31005 
  type: LoadBalancer
```

tenant2-app deployments & service yamls

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: tenant2-app-deployment
  namespace: tenant2-namespace 
spec: 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: tenant2-app 
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 1 pods matching the template 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: tenant2-app 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: tenant2-app-container 
        image: tenant2-app-dock-img:v1 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 8085 
--- 
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service  
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: tenant2-app-service
  namespace: tenant2-namespace  
spec: 
  selector: 
    app: tenant2-app 
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP 
    port: 8085 
    targetPort: 8085 
    nodePort: 31006 
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Updates 2 :

db-pod1.yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
      creationTimestamp: null
      generation: 1
      labels:
        k8s-app: tenant1-db
      name: tenant1-db
    spec:
      progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
      replicas: 1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 10
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: tenant1-db
      strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 25%
          maxUnavailable: 25%
        type: RollingUpdate
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            k8s-app: tenant1-db
          name: tenant1-db
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: tenant1-pv-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: tenant1-pv-claim
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: tenant1db
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            image: postgres:11.5-alpine
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: tenant1-db
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
              name: tenant1-pv-storage
            resources: {}
            securityContext:
              privileged: false
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
```

db-pod2.ymal

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    k8s-app: tenant2-db
  name: tenant2-db
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant2-db
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: tenant2-db
      name: tenant2-db
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: tenant2-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tenant2-pv-claim
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: tenant2db
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        image: postgres:11.5-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: tenant2-db
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
          name: tenant2-pv-storage
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
```

Update 3 :

```
kubectl get svc -n default
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP          5d2h
nginx           ClusterIP      10.100.24.46     <none>           80/TCP           5d1h
tenant1-db   LoadBalancer   10.111.165.169   10.111.165.169   5432:30810/TCP   4d22h
tenant2-db   LoadBalancer   10.101.75.77     10.101.75.77     5432:30811/TCP   2d22h

kubectl get svc -n tenant1-namespace
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                               PORT(S)          AGE
tenant1-app-service   LoadBalancer   10.111.200.49   10.111.200.49                             8085:31005/TCP   3d
tenant1-db         ExternalName   <none>          tenant1-db.default.svc.cluster.local   5432/TCP         2d23h

kubectl get svc -n tenant2-namespace
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                               PORT(S)          AGE
tenant1-db         ExternalName   <none>         tenant1-db.default.svc.cluster.local   5432/TCP         2d23h
tenant2-app-service   LoadBalancer   10.99.139.18   10.99.139.18                              8085:31006/TCP   2d23h
```

Comment: so the connection from tenant2-app to tenant1-db works? Share all the 4 pod yaml

Comment: @Arghya I have updated ques

Comment: @DeveloperDesk which CNI are you using? Not all of them support NetworkPolicy.

Comment: I am using Cilium kubernetes network policy as I am trying it on my local machine ubuntu having minikube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors) Let's understand the below policy that you have for tenant2.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces-except-specific-pod-2
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant2-db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: development
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tenant2-app
```

The above network policy that you have defined has two elements in the form array which says allow connections from Pods in the local (default) namespace with the label `app=tenant2-app`, or from any Pod in any namespace with the label `name=development`.

If you merge the rules into a single rule as below it should solve the issue.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces-except-specific-pod-2
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant2-db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: tenant2-development
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tenant2-app
```

Above network policy means allow connections from Pods with the label `app=tenant2-app` in namespaces with the label `name=tenant2-development`.

Add a label `name=tenant2-development` to the `tenant2-ns` namespace.

Do the same exercise for tenant1 as well as bellow:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces-except-specific-pod-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: tenant1-db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: tenant1-development
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tenant1-app
```

Add a label `name=tenant1-development` to the `tenant1-ns` namespace.

Comment: I tried above but still tenant2-app able to access tenant1-db.

Comment: can you share the both db pod yaml as well in the question

Comment: Looks okay...did you add label to the tenant namespaces?

Comment: Yeah I added labels

Comment: I had created external service of type=ExternalName to access db pod from default namespace. Is this problem ? I have updated in ques